# What would happen if Voldemort kept creating Horcruxes?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux

I know there is a limit on how much Voldemort could tear his soul, but if he surpassed the limit his soul could handle, and he died: wouldn't he just be resurrected by one of his horcruxes yet again? Is it some kind of loophole?

Comment: The real issue is not dying, but having his personality fragmented to a point where his existence can no longer be sustained. He would become a mere spirit of malice that gnaws itself in the shadows, but cannot again grow or take shape.

Comment: This question is not primarily opinion-based - the answer is based on the books.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Creating multiple Horcruxes made his soul unstable and more likely to break apart.**

The Dark Lord couldn't create too many Horcruxes. The more he created, the more unstable it became, so he wouldn't be able to create unlimited Horcruxes. He'd have to limit it somewhat. Creating Horcruxes makes the soul more and more unstable with each new Horcrux. The book that provides the instructions for making Horcruxes warns about this.

> “And the more I’ve read about them,’ said Hermione, ‘the more horrible they seem, and the less I can believe that he actually made six. It warns in this book how unstable you make the rest of your soul by ripping it, and that’s just by making one Horcrux!” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 6 (The Ghoul in Pyjamas)*</sup></sub>

In fact, he had already made his soul unstable enough before even making Nagini a Horcrux, that a piece unintentionally broke off and embedded itself in Harry.

> “He had rendered his soul so unstable that it broke apart when he committed those acts of unspeakable evil, the murder of your parents, the attempted killing of a child. But what escaped from that room was even less than he knew. He left more than his body behind. He left part of himself latched to you, the would-be victim who had survived.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 35 (King’s Cross)*</sup></sub>

Comment: Quickly accepted before question is closed *looks around fidgetly*

Comment: I suspect that his sense of right and wrong would eventually also become so reduced that additional killings wouldn't count as murder, making it impossible for him to create more horcruxes.